# Error Group by string column name (run time column name)

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I am encountering an error using the q.GroupBy method below.
It says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 
>            `System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<TRet, TModel>>` to 
>            `System.Linq.IQueryable<TModel>`

Above is error thrown

```
    public static IQueryable<TModel> GroupByDynamic<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> q, string name)
    {
        Type entityType = typeof(TModel);
        PropertyInfo p = entityType.GetProperty(name);
        MethodInfo m = typeof(QueryableHelper).GetMethod("GroupByProperty").MakeGenericMethod(entityType, p.PropertyType);          
        return (IQueryable<TModel>)m.Invoke(null, new object[] { q, p });
    }


    public static IQueryable<TModel> GroupByProperty<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)  
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
        Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(TRet));
        return q.GroupBy(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TRet>>(se, pe));
    }
```

The following q.OrderBy statement works without any issue

```
   public static IQueryable<TModel> OrderByProperty<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
        Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(TRet));
        return q.OrderBy(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TRet>>(se, pe));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply select clause after grouping and change the method output.

```
public static IQueryable<TRet> GroupByProperty<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)
{
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
    Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(TRet));
    return q.GroupBy(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TRet>>(se, pe)).Select(x => x.Key);
}
```

The Func input is already `TModel` and you want to apply group over this entity. So i assume that you want to select `Key` by grouping it. And this is why change the method return type.

Another option is that you can change the return method sign as `IQueryable<IGrouping<TRet, TModel>>` as the error tells.

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TRet, TModel>> GroupByProperty<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)
{
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
    Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(TRet));
    return q.GroupBy(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TRet>>(se, pe));
}
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<dynamic, TModel>> GroupByDynamic<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> q, string name)
{
    Type entityType = typeof(TModel);
    PropertyInfo p = entityType.GetProperty(name);
    MethodInfo m = typeof(B).GetMethod("GroupByProperty").MakeGenericMethod(entityType, p.PropertyType);
    return (IQueryable<IGrouping<dynamic, TModel>>)m.Invoke(null, new object[] { q, p });
}
```

Comment: Of course you should change the return sign too "IQueryable<TModel> GroupByDynamic<TModel>"

Comment: i dont want to select any thing here, rather i will select after invoking this
Employees.BuildQuery(extra_search).GroupByDynamic("Region").Select(x => x.Key)

Comment: Thanks  @Stormcloak 
But when i change return sign for GroupByDynamic, I encounter below error
The type arguments for method 'QueryableHelper.GroupByDynamic<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel>, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage

Comment: Wow, this is exactly i was looking.
Thanks a lot for the help @ Stormcloak

Comment: how can i select count of other property based on selection

Comment: Do you mean "Employees.BuildQuery(extra_search).GroupByDynamic("Region").‌​Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Count() })" ?

Comment: I am attempting something like this, but i cant.

       var groupcount = Employees.BuildQuery(reqfilter.extra_search).GroupBy(x=>x.Region).Select(group => group.Sum(x=>x.GetType().GetProperty("Amount"))).ToList();

Comment: There is no required for reflection. Just sum TModel property; "Employees.BuildQuery(reqfilter.extra_search).GroupBy(x=>x.Re‌​gion).Select(group => group.Sum(x=> x.Amount)).ToList()"

Comment: this Amount is Dynamic, 
That can be any other long field from model
Thats y i am trying to use reflection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163719/discussion-between-stormcloak-and-user3815413).